# Understanding Add Surface Info Tool (Average Slope) vs Slope Tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4, slope, watershed

What is the difference between the values calculated using the slope tool vs the slope option in the add surface information tool?

I am making a map that displays watershed slope (using the slope tool) and want to also show stream slope (using add the add surface info tool) but not sure if the calculated values are saying the same thing.

Add surface info tool (average slope bit):
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-surface-information.htm

Slope tool:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-slope-works.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C81D5590295342FF8C730744027A96C6

Here is an image showing the terrain slope and three oddly colored streams with their slope data (bottom left corner, first three rows):
[image]

Here is another pic of only landscape slope:
[image]

Comment: What happened when you tested the two tools and compared the results?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, PolyGeo. Both result in percent - the numbers calculated for the streams seem possible when compared to the watershed landscape values, but I'd like to be sure before moving forward. I can post a picture in a bit if that would help.

Comment: That may be helpful to potential answerers of your question.

Comment: Alright, I'll snap a picture when I get to the office. Why the downvotes? Has this question been asked before? I didn't see anything similar in previous posts.

Comment: People downvote for many reasons. A good way to avoid them is to include as much detail and research as you can at the outset.

Comment: At this point, I'm considering masking the major stream shapefiles to the DEM, running the slope tool, and then mean zonal statistics. This is similar to how I created the above watershed slope map. What do you think, PolyGeo?

Comment: I'm not a potential answerer of your question because I rarely work with ArcGIS Spatial Analyst.